# Получить список самых больших чисел Python

Tags: python

У меня, например, есть список `[1, 2, 7, 7]`, как мне из него получить список самых больших чисел? Чтобы получилось `[7, 7]`.

Я пробовал с помощью `heapq.nlargest(n, iterable, key=None)`, но там необходимо указывать количество элементов. А мне надо чтобы я не зная какое количество повторяющихся самых больших чисел есть в списке, мог получить список с этими самыми числами.

Comment: Найти максимальное число, сосчитать их количество. Готово.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Держи

```
data = [1, 2, 7, 7]
maxx = max(data)
a = [i for i in data if i == maxx]
```

Comment: Совсем не оптимальное решение, потому что максимум ищется столько раз, сколько элементов в списке.

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо, изменил

Answer (score 7):

Можно так сделать:

```py
src = [1, 2, 7, 7]
src_max = max(src)
dest = [src_max for i in range(src.count(src_max))]
```

Answer (score 6):

Разве никто не знает, что список можно умножить на число?

```
n = max(data)
amount = data.count(n)
result = [n] * amount
```

В одну строчку (хотя и не совсем оптимально, максимум ищется дважды)

```
result = [max(data)] * data.count(max(data))
```

Comment: `[x := max(data)] * data.count(x)`

Comment: @КириллМалышев во, да, отлично!

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить такое решение:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 7, 7]
max_number = max(my_list)
numbers = my_list.count(max_number)
answer = []

for i in range(numbers):
    answer.append(max_number)
    
print(answer)
```

P.S Постарался расписать максимально подробно и понятно.